# Apply differential equations operator to image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, differential-equations

I have a differential equation in the form of:

```
x'(t) + x(t) = u(t)
```

where `x'(t)` is the first order derivative of `x(t)`. This is a homework questions which asks to discretize the equation with forward difference approximation, and then to apply the resulting operator over an image (using MATLAB). I'm not asking for the solution, I'm just not clear on how to actually apply the operator to the image. 
I replaced `x'(t)` with `[x(t+h)-x(t)]/h` which I suppose makes the equation discrete, but I don't know how to go further (that is, as I said, apply this operator to an image using MATLAB).
Any help/references I can check out?

**EDIT**
Full text of the exercise:
[image]

Comment: @Shai I don't know. I'm just given the equation and I'm told that I have to make it discrete. Then I'm told to apply it to a grayscale image along each row/column with a certain timestep = 0.5.

Comment: @TheCodingMonk: With the provided information it's not possible to solve. What is the (unfiltered) image? `x` or `u`. And what is `t`? It usually stands for time, is this a series of pictures?

Comment: @Daniel I've edited the question and added the full text of the exercise. That's all the information I have. As you can see it's just a single picture and variables are not defined, that's probably why I'm having difficulties solving this. Probably some unspecified assumptions are made on the value of x and u, but I have no idea about it.

Comment: u should be the image anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your initial ideas are correct.

t is the coordinate along the image row or in the second step along the column. What is not clear with the given choice of h=0.5 is the distance from pixel to pixel. Assuming it is 1 gives a doubling of the image size and requires interpolation between pixels.

As a filter, the solution is obtained via convolution with the sequence

```
[ 1, exp(-h), exp(-2*h), exp(-3*h),... ]*h
```

or

```
[ 1, q, q^2, q^3, ... ]*h
```

where q is the approximation of exp(-h) resulting from the discretization.

Or inverse convolution with `[ 1, -q]`.